# Swapping tags with words in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

The idea is that I have a form with a text area, and then a list of words in a dropdown.

In the text input, the user can type their sentences, and use a tag such as `{product}` to where they want to hot swap the word out.

I have this working for the most part, but as I am manipulating the value of my input to change the tag, and then using an onChange function, it overwrites the tags with the word preventing them from being changed again.

For example:

```
  manipulateText =(text) => {
    if(text) return text.replace("{product}", this.state.type)
    else return null
  }

  onChange =(e, l) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.id]: l - e.target.value.length,
      [`${e.target.id}_value`]: e.target.value
    })
  }

<Input
  type="text"
  name="brand"
  id="brand"
  onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e, 35)}
  value={this.manipulateText(this.state.brand_value)}/>
```

Does anyone know how I can make this so that where the tag was used, its always swappable?

A working example is available here: https://codesandbox.io/s/7k264xllv1
If you use `{product}` as the tag, you can change it, but if you type after changing, it is no longer changeable

Comment: Is it possible to maintain the unmodified text on input and display it formatted somewhere else? This way is easier to accomplish it:
https://codesandbox.io/s/jz55y8l2jy

Comment: I don't really want to do that, to be honest as it means doubling up my content.  I've been trying to find a way of displaying something else in the Input, rather than what the user types, but so I've not found a way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you need, maybe replacing the `{product}` tag and the old selected product should solve.

Something like this

```
  manipulateText = text => {
    console.log(text, this.state);

    let result = null

    if (text) {
      result = text.replace(/{product}/g, this.state.type);

      if (this.state.old) {
        result = result.replace(new RegExp(this.state.old, "g"), this.state.type)
      }
    }
    return result
  }
```

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/2vzppzj1y0